# How can I debug after certain processing is done-Java

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I need to debug my java code but only after certain processing is done and I reach a point where it faults down.

For Eg:-I am preprocessing my code and I have created a filter which would refrain from inserting into database if its size is less then 5.And I name the group which is inserted as 1,2....My problem is the number 121 has a size of 4 and its getting inserted into the database.So how should i debug so that I can start directly at 121 ignoring all the previous sequence number.I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: create a conditional breakpoint.  Firstly toggle the breakpoint and edit the breakpoint properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use conditional break points as following:

1. Put the break point at specific line.
2. Right click on break point.
3. Select "Breakpoint Properties".
4. In it select "Enable Condition". In it you can set condition for break point for your variable having value of 121. Ctrl + Space will also work in the box for code assist.

Comment: Never knew this was a feature. I've always added in if statements jsut to trigger a conditional breakpoint. This is good to know :)

Answer (score 2):

If the number is fixed always, you can put a temporary check condition for example

```
if(number == 121) {
    continue;
}
```

And put a break point at continue.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a breakpoint from the code line you want to start debugging. Then you can chose to  Step into or step over etc.

Shortcut for debugging in Eclipse are

```
F5  Step into
F6  Step over
F7  Run to return
F8  Resume
F9   Relaunch last
F11 Run/debug last
Ctrl F11    Run
Ctrl Shift B    Toggle breakpoint
Ctrl D  Display
Ctrl Q  Inspect
Ctrl R  Run to line
Ctrl U  Run snippet
```

You can even evaluate expression during debugging on a particular breakpoint. Check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) tutorial for more details.